# Istio 1.5.1 - Security - Authorisation Policy - 503 Response code

Tags: authorization, istio

Need help with setting up authorisation policy. Kubernetes on premise setup with Istio version: 1.5.1

Getting 200 Ok when there is no authorisation policy. 503 Response Code when authorisation policy applied.

Ingressgateway access log (working when there is **no** authorization policy)

> [2020-05-15T07:08:30.278Z] "GET /v1/delegation/test HTTP/1.1" **200** -
>   "-" "-" 0 4 81 79 "10.40.172.33,10.32.0.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>   10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36"
>   "a19876b4-12ee-9172-aa93-e405a1a89c6b" "[REPLACED-SERVERNAME]"
>   "10.32.0.150:9091"
>   outbound|9091||[REPLACED].[REPLACED-NAMESPACENAME].svc.cluster.local
>   10.32.0.153:56224 10.32.0.153:80 10.32.0.1:15044 - -

Corresponding application pod Istio-proxy log (working When there is no authorization policy)

> [2020-05-15T07:08:30.279Z] "- - -" 0 - "-" "-" 1805 142 60133 - "-"
>   "-" "-" "-" "127.0.0.1:9091"
>   inbound|9091||[REPLACED].[REPLACED-NAMESPACENAME].svc.cluster.local
>   127.0.0.1:33222 10.32.0.150:9091 10.32.0.153:56224 outbound_.9091_._.[REPLACED].[REPLACED-NAMESPACENAME].svc.cluster.local

Implementing below authorization Policy

```
$ cat [REPLACED]-auth-policy.yaml apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1 kind: AuthorizationPolicy metadata:   name: [REPLACED]-auth-policy   namespace: [REPLACED-NAMESPACENAME] spec:   selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: [REPLACED]   action: ALLOW   rules:
  - to:
    - operation:
        paths: ["/v1/delegation/test"]
```

authorizationpolicy.security.istio.io/[REPLACED]-auth-policy created

Ingressgateway access log (NOT working when authorization policy **applied**)

> [2020-05-15T07:12:54.333Z] "GET /v1/delegation/test HTTP/1.1" **503** UC
>   "-" "-" 0 95 9 - "10.40.172.33,10.32.0.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>   10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36"
>   "b1177978-3151-9629-b8cf-d97f6dc40fb6" "[REPLACED-SERVERNAME]"
>   "10.32.0.150:9091"
>   outbound|9091||[REPLACED].[REPLACED-NAMESPACENAME].svc.cluster.local
>   10.32.0.153:60850 10.32.0.153:80 10.32.0.1:33145 - -

Corresponding applicaiton pod Istio-proxy log (NOT working When authorization policy **applied**)

> [2020-05-15T06:43:07.789Z] "- - -" 0 - "-" "-" 968 1796 1764128 - "-"
>   "-" "-" "-" "10.41.88.60:1282" PassthroughCluster 10.32.0.150:52592
>   10.41.88.60:1282 10.32.0.150:52590 - - [2020-05-15T07:12:54.334Z] "- - -" 0 - "-" "-" 0 0 8 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "127.0.0.1:9091" inbound|9091||[REPLACED].[REPLACED-NAMESPACENAME].svc.cluster.local
>   127.0.0.1:37848 10.32.0.150:9091 10.32.0.153:60850 outbound_.9091_._.[REPLACED].[REPLACED-NAMESPACENAME].svc.cluster.local
>   - [2020-05-15T06:43:38.749Z] "- - -" 0 - "-" "-" 968 1796 1757489 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "10.41.88.60:1282" PassthroughCluster
>   10.32.0.150:53270 10.41.88.60:1282 10.32.0.150:53268 - -

Comment: Maybe that's because of strict mtls? What if you change it to permissive? If you want to check that there is an [example](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authentication/authn-policy/#globally-enabling-istio-mutual-tls-in-strict-mode) with strict, change STRICT to PERMISSIVE and apply it to your cluster.

Comment: @jt97 Thanks for your response. Not enabled mtls. I could not see any PeerAuthentication as well.

Comment: As it's 1.5.1 mtls is enabled by default, more about it [here](https://istio.io/news/releases/1.5.x/announcing-1.5/change-notes/#security). Graduated auto mutual TLS from alpha to beta. This feature is now enabled by default. Another thing, could you try to use something other than paths? For example get/post like [there](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-deny/#explicitly-deny-a-request)?

Answer (score 0):

In the Kubernetes service definition, I had to specifically name the TCP port “http”.  Naming the post http allows a DNS SRV query for _http._tcp.my-service.my-ns.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#dns

“Kubernetes also supports DNS SRV (Service) records for named ports. If the "my-service.my-ns" Service has a port named "http" with the protocol set to TCP , you can do a DNS SRV query for _http._tcp.my-service.my-ns to discover the port number for "http" , as well as the IP address.”

Comment: if i understood u, should i deploy my service as http instead of: name: tcp, protocol: TCP ?  any time i apply an AuthorizationPolicy  &  RequestAuthentication, my request status are always 503 i wonder why, can u help ?

Comment: Yeah `name: http, protocol: TCP`.  Regarding the help, you can post a question and tag me, I will try to help.

Comment: hi @cory-silva here is my repo  github.com/jamesmedice/Istio-Rbac-Policy-Mesh , in case i m using istio gateway at 31400 port, the security with RequestAuthentication & AuthorizationPolicy, the request are throwing 503 , the repo for security is  github.com/jamesmedice/Istio-Security-VS-Mesh , istio version 1.5.1 , tks for ur support

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmedice/Istio-Rbac-Policy-Mesh/blob/master/istio/service.yaml#L12

That line should read `name: http`

Comment: just did that and is retrieving 503 Service Unavailable, in case my ingress-gateway has       port: name: http   number: 31400 protocol: HTTP, the project of security is github.com/jamesmedice/Istio-Security-VS-Mesh , istio 1.5.8